# creating templates in angular 2 application

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4

I am trying to implement a simple application in angular 2 .

i designed my home page with a top nav bar and side nav bar.

### Below shown is the code for my home page template

### home.component.html

```
<div class="well sidebar-nav">
    <ul class="nav nav-list">
        <li class="nav-header">Status At A Glance</li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Remaining</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">In Progress</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Accepted</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>  

<p> <strong> Welcome to eSpace Home </strong></p>
<img src="/../../assets/i9.jpeg" class="img-rounded" alt="home" height="200" width="600">
```

### Below shown is the screen shot of my home page

[image]

As shown in the above image i am unable to reduce the width of my side nav and my content i.e "welcome to espace home" and image is being aligned below my side nav.

can any body please help me fix this by guiding me how can i reduce the width of my side nav and how can i align my content right side of my side nav bar.

Comment: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: ok i will refer this .. but please can you help me out here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/). For example:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-4">
      Your nav bar
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-8">
      Your content
   </div>
</div>
```